ShadCN-Vue installation - did not recognize object of type "TSInterfaceHeritage"
I'm trying to install ShadCN for VueJS but I'm encountering a weird error after successful installation.
I've followed each step of the installation guide under:
https://www.shadcn-vue.com/docs/installation/vite
Terminal/Vite says everything went successfully after step number 8.
Step 9 on the docs:
When I'm trying to add a button with: npx shadcn-vue@latest add button
in order to verify that the installation worked / use the a component
I'm encountering the followin error:
Error: did not recognize object of type "TSInterfaceHeritage"
What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?
Thanks.

There seems to be an ongoing issue with the latest version.
As a workaround you could install using an older version of the CLI tool:
npx shadcn-vue@0.10 add button


Thank you for the hint. I was hoping to offer ShadCN as an alternative to Vuetify at my new work. However, running into this issue as a first dev-experience made think twice about this.

My experience was all good with the previous version. The latest one seems to have few bugs. @user3135691
